# Python List Comprehension adds another dimension in Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, list-comprehension

Trying to learn list comprehensions to streamline code. However, this one below is adding an extra dimension when I print out the shape. What am I doing wrong? I thought this was a simple textbook case for list comprehension...

```
i = []

for item in intensities_copy:
    clipped = item[:, q_min_idx:q_max_idx+1]
    i.append(clipped)

i = np.array(i)

i2 = [[item[:, q_min_idx:q_max_idx+1]] for item in intensities_copy]

i2 = np.array(i2)

print(i.shape)
print(i2.shape)
```

Here's the output:

```
(100, 1800, 740)
(100, 1, 1800, 740)
```

Comment: Why do you have an extra pair of `[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loose the extra brackets and you will get the same shape (that is where you get extra dimension):

```
i2 = [item[:, q_min_idx:q_max_idx+1] for item in intensities_copy]
```

Note, that `append` adds the *whole element* to the list, whereas adding the *content* of element would be like `i += clipped`

Comment: Thanks! I figured this would be solved rather quick. I see what I did wrong